# php scope issue for function checking isset

Tags: php, scope, isset

I need a function that will take a string as an argument, then check to see if a variable named the same thing as that string is set.

This works...

```
$foo = 'foosuccess';
$property = 'foo';
if(isset($$property)){
echo $$property;
}
```

This doesn't, because within test(), $$property2 is the wrong scope.

```
$huh = 'huhsuccess';
$huh = test("huh");
function test($property2){
    if(isset($$property2)){
        echo $$property2;
}
}
```

How can I fix the function so $$property2 refers to the same scope as the caller's context? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: The only acceptable way for data to appear in the function scope - is passing via arguments.

Comment: @zerkms, so, is there a way to pass a reference to the variable that i'm checking? the problem i run into trying it that way, is that if the variable is not set to begin with, i can't reference it. and if it is set, then there's no point...

Comment: ok, i think i figured it out for my purposes (if anyone's interested...)

    //uncomment to get success
    //$huh = 'huhsuccess';
    $huh = test($huh);

    echo $huh;

    function test(&$property2) {
       if(isset($property2)) {
           return $property2;
       } else {
        return 'not set!';
       }
    }
    die;

Comment: Why do you neeed `&$property` (I mean - reference)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$huh = 'huhsuccess';
test("huh");

function test($property2) {
    global $$property2;

    if(isset($$property2)) {
        echo $$property2;
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work, but even if it did, i don't want the variable to be in the global scope. i need it to be in the scope of the caller. (fwiw, this may not be the best practice...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function test($s) 
{ 
  return isset($GLOBALS[$s]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think i figured it out for my purposes (if anyone's interested...)

```
//uncomment to get success
//$huh = 'huhsuccess';
$huh = test($huh);

echo $huh;

function test(&$property2) {
   if(isset($property2)) {
       return $property2;
   } else {
       return 'not set!';
   }
}
die;
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with `eval()`:

```
   $foo = 'foosuccess';
    $property = 'foo';
    if(eval('isset($'.$property.')'){
    echo $$property;
    }
```